# Update GUI from Task

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5

I'm trying to create a method that will encapsulate all GUI operations from a different thread, however when I use it nothing happens and no exception is thrown.
This is what I got:

```
    private Task t1;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoStuffInTask())
            .ContinueWith(tsk => Finished(tsk));
    }

    private void DoStuffInTask()
    {
        //doing important stuff...
        for (int i = 0; i < Int16.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            //Text is a property that raises INotifyPropertyChanged event
            RunOnGui(() => { Text = i.ToString(); }); // not working, not throwing exception
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Text = i.ToString()); // works fine
        }
    }

    private void RunOnGui(Action action)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => action);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => action);
```

Compiles to the overload `public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TResult> callback);`

Your code is executing a `Func<Action>` which just returns the action, not executing it.

What you need is this

```
private void RunOnGui(Action action)
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);//Note no lambda here
}
```